# Efficient way to implement matrix multiplication when one matrix is extremely wide?

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to multiply 3 matrices, `A: 3000x100, B: 100x100, C: 100x3.6MM`.  I currently am just using normal matrix multiplication in PyTorch

```
A_gpu = torch.from_numpy(A)
B_gpu = torch.from_numpy(B)
C_gpu = torch.from_numpy(C)
D_gpu = (A_gpu @ B_gpu @ C_gpu.t()).t()
```

C is very wide so the data reuse on gpu is limited but are there other ways to speed this up? I have a machine with 4x GPUs.

Comment: do you look to split/extend the multiplication on all 4 GPUs ?

Comment: I just started working with PyTorch, but I can look into that.

Comment: What does `MM` mean? Is it a typo or do you mean `M` times `M`, that is 10^6 \* 10^6 = 10^12 = `T`?

Comment: It means Million.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have four GPUs, you can harness them to perform efficient matrix multiplication. Notice however that the results of the multiplication has size 3000x3600000, which takes up 40GB in single precision floating point (fp32). Unless you have a large enough RAM for the CPU, you cannot store the results of this computation on the RAM.

A possible solution for this is to break up the large matrix `C` into four smaller chunks, perform the matrix multiplication of each chunk on a different GPU, and keep the result on the GPU. Provided that each GPU has at least 10GB of memory, you will have enough memory for this.

If you do have also enough CPU memory, you can then move the results of all four GPUs onto the CPU and concatenate them (in fact, in this case you could have used only a single GPU and transfer the results from GPU to CPU each time). Otherwise, you can keep the results chunked on the GPUs, and you need to remember and keep track that the four chunks are actually part of one matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

number_of_gpus = 4

# create four matrics
A = np.random.normal(size=(3000,100))
B = np.random.normal(size=(100,100))
C = np.random.normal(size=(100,3600000))

# convert them to pytorch fp32 tensors
A = torch.from_numpy(A).float()
B = torch.from_numpy(B).float()
C = torch.from_numpy(C).float()

# calcualte `A@B`, which is easy
AB = A@B

# split the large matrix `C` into 4 smaller chunks along the second dimension. 
# we assume here that the size of the second dimension of `C` is divisible by 4.  
C_split = torch.split(C,C.shape[1]//number_of_gpus,dim=1)

# loop over the four GPUs, and perform the calculation on each using the corresponding chunk of `C`
D_split = []
for i in range(number_of_gpus):
    device = 'cuda:{:d}'.format(i)
    D_split.append( AB.to(device) @ C_split[i].to(device))

# DO THIS ONLY IF YOU HAVE ENOUGH CPU MEMORY!! :
D = torch.cat([d.cpu() for d in D_split],dim=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple GPUs, you can distribute the computation on all of them using PyTorch's [`DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.DataParallel). It will split (parallelize) the multiplication of the columns of the matrix `C_gpu` among the GPUs.

Here's how:

First, import the modules and prepare the matrices:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

A_gpu = torch.from_numpy(A).float()
B_gpu = torch.from_numpy(B).float()
C_gpu = torch.from_numpy(C).float()
```

Next, create a [`Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear) "layer" without bias. What this layer does is exactly matrix multiplication. The input size will be the size of each column of `C_gpu`, and the output size will be the size of each column of the result.

```
mat_mult = nn.Linear(in_features=C_gpu.shape[0],out_features=A_gpu.shape[0],bias=False)
```

Set the matrix (=weight) of the layer to be `A_gpu @ B_gpu`, which is a small matrix that can be quickly computed without parallelization (although you could parallelize it as well if you want).

```
mat_mult.weight.data = A_gpu @ B_gpu
```

Convert the layer into a DataParallel instance. This means that it will automatically parallelize computation along the "batch" dimension. The argument `device_ids` is a list of indices of your GPUs (4 of them, in your case).

```
mat_mult_gpu = nn.DataParallel(mat_mult,device_ids=[0,1,2,3]).to('cuda:0')
```

Now you can feed the matrix `C_gpu` into the layer, and the computation will be parallel along the its large dimension:

```
D_gpu  = mat_mult_gpu(C_gpu.t())
```

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** When writing this answer, I did not have access to multiple GPUs to actually test this proposed solution. I will appreciate if any of the readers will confirm that it indeed works (and even better - time the solution and compare to a single GPU)

---

**EDIT1:** I now tried this code on multiple GPUs (four Nvidia Tesla P100), and turns out it gives an out of memory error. I'll keep this solution here as a reference though, since it does work for sizes up to about 400K (instead of 3.6M).

Also, This solution will still work also for sizes 3.6M if you divide `C` into smaller chunks, feed each chunk into `mat_mult_gpu`, and then concatenate the results on the CPU. Note that you need a lot of CPU memory for this to work, since the result has size `3K-by-3.6M` which in fp32 takes about 40GB. (alternatively, you can save each chunk to the disk without concatenating chunks).

Comment: I changed in dimension to `C_gpu.shape[1]` as this is the column size when the matrix is transposed, removed the transpose in `D_gpu = ...` and added `.cuda()` to `DataParallel` object. I get CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 23GB.

Comment: I added to the answer the allocation to the cuda device, as it is required indeed. However, I don't think you needed to do the other things. The transpose is there to make the large dimension be the batch dimension (that is, the first dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your matrix `C`, a sparse matrix, may reduce size and computation time, e.g. you save only columns that are not 0, maybe [torch reference](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) may help.